# Compare responsibility among copy-left license

Tags: licensing, open-source

I have checked out many source about the free and open source licenses ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_and_open-source_software_licenses)), but what I really want to know what is our responsibility when we use the open source that has these licenses.
For example:

Zlib:
you must not claim that you wrote the original software.
If you use this software in a product, an acknowledgement in the product documentation would be appreciated but is not required. (from Irrlicht's readme.txt file)

LGPL:
dynamically linking to it from a closed source app is allowed, but also means any changes made to soft (which has LGPL) itself do need to be made available publicly. (source: from [a comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/1nbb0j/using_sdl_audio_and_sdl_mixer_vs_openal/cchtqt0/))

GPL: The license for libmad is GPL, which means that in order to use it your application must also be GPL (source: from SDL Mixer README.txt file)

Please make a quick compare like that so I can understand fully about my responsibly when I use an open source software for my project.

**PS:**
In this question, I like to limit the comparison to the most popular copy-left licenses:

- Apache License
- BSD License
- GNU General Public License
- GNU Lesser General Public License
- MIT license
- zlib/libpng license

Comment: It looks like you've already done the comparison. What are you looking for others to add?

Comment: @DMGregory: Thanks for your comment, the comparison I've given is very small. I want a more complete comparison, like what about GPL version 1, version 2,... .

Comment: This question can also  be understood like this: What you must do when you package an open source software into your product? zlib: just don't claim it's yours, LGPL: public the changes of the open source if any, GPL: make your app open source too, MIT: put the name of the open source somewhere in your product,... .

Comment: Then you should ask about the specific license and version you're interested in, not leave the question open-ended. Broad questions without a clear scope tend to be closed here. You can always post a second question later if you think of another license/aspect you need clarified. Lastly, you should also consider whether game developers are the right experts to be asking about this. Copy-left licences are used in all kinds of fields, not just games, and are more of a legal issue, so you may get better answers on the Law StackEchange.

Comment: @DMGregory : Thank DMGregory, I have updated the question to limit the scope of the question